# An example of infinite Betti number refers to G-covering, and the motivation of G-covering

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, betti-numbers

I saw from a book that if G is infinite, then when considering G-covering: $p:X'\to X$, the P-th Betti number of $X'$ can be infinite. Can you give me an example of that. Also I am curious why we need to consider the G-covering.

Comment: This can even happen when $G=1$, since you are making no assumptions about $X$. For more interesting examples, take $X$ the wedge of two circles and $X'\to X$ the covering corresponding to the commutator subgroup of $F_2=\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: @studiosus Thank you very much